# Xero Tax calculation

Tags: php, xero-api

I have an invoice and a few payments has the amount of 7.7454. For these payments, we have 10% GST included. When we generate an invoice with 10% tax, this 7.7454 value gets the wrong tax amount. It will add 0.01 extra amount to it. I want to know how to fix this and may I know whether Xero will round 7.7454 to 7.75 before calculating the tax?

I tried adding values with four decimal places but it still looks like rounding it to 2 decimal places which gives a wrong value

Answer (score 0):

The line items are rounded to 2 dp and then the tax calculated on the line items.

I have added a link to a How To Guide explaining how tax is calculated and how to handle any rounding differences.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/how-to-guides/rounding-in-xero